# What to do with [bugs] questions now that version 9 is released?

Tags: discussion

@MikeHoneychurch asked in chat what we should do with [questions that have been tagged as [bugs]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) now that version 9 was released.  Some of these bugs might be fixed in version 9.  This post is to start a discussion for deciding this.

Answer (score 11):

I propose that:

- If the bug is still present, tag it with the affected versions (most likely [version-8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-8) and [version-9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-9))
- If the bug is fixed:

  - Tag it with [version-8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-8) only (possibly earlier if there's a special reason to do so)
  - Add a visible (bolded?) note in the question explaining that the bug was fixed in version 9. (I didn't propose adding an answer because many of these will already have accepted answers.)  I think this information is going to be useful for people who might still be on earlier versions.

I went ahead and did this in this question: [Issue with PathGraph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6353/issue-with-pathgraph)

(A possible reason not to do this too quickly is to avoid the front page being spammed with edits.)

Comment: maybe post the notice in the answer instead of the question... not everyone reads the question thoroughly, but they're bound to read an accepted answer, especially if they're looking for a bugfix

Comment: @rm-rf That makes sense. Wherever it's more clear/noticeable.