# How to write the bug banner for different bugfix versions?

Tags: discussion

The bug mentioned in these two related questions [(94496)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94496/clipplanes-on-translated-3d-objects-crash-front-end) and [(113527)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113527/clipplanes-crashed-in-v10-4) seems to be fixed in different versions.

On Windows, the bugfix version is 11.0.0. On MacOS, reading the comments, it is 10.4.0.

For each of these questions, I am wondering whether this:

> Bug introduced in ... and fixed in 10.4.0 (MacOS) and 11.0.0 (Windows)

would be an appropriate form.

**How the bug banner should be written for OS-dependent *bugfix version*?**

From a quick search, OS-dependent *bugs* do not seem to be an issue, the OS specification being either part of the question (see, e.g., [(16683)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16683/discrepancy-with-takewhile-between-randominteger-result-and-list-on-linux) and [(111719)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111719/cant-open-mathematica-on-linux-mint-17-3-kde)) or part of the banner (see, e.g., [(89152)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89152/version-10-2-key-shortcuts-for-matching-brackets-do-not-work)).

**Update 1.** Following the comment of ilian, I would propose instead something like

> Windows: Bug introduced in ... and fixed in  11.0.0
>
> MacOS: Bug introduced in ... and fixed in 10.4.0

**Update 2.** *(Follows QuantumDot comment)* Bug banner standardization was discussed before in this [post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching), but the case I mentioned here was not addressed previously as far as I know.

Would there be any advantages of having a standard header for these cases as well?

Comment: I would be wary of calling it the same bug, if it is indeed fixed in different releases on different operating systems...

Comment: @ilian Good point, I have updated the question.

Comment: Is it completely necessary to standardize how we write this note?  As long as it is clear, I don't think we really need any sort of standardization.  After all, we aren't developing *Mathematica*.

Comment: @QuantumDot I saw quite a few posts on Meta about how to deal with [tag:bugs] questions and how to standardize them. The bug banner idea was initiated in this [post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/how-should-we-tag-longstanding-bugs-that-have-been-fixed), and proposition of its standardization in this [one](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching?noredirect=1&lq=1). You can see further discussion about standardization in the comments of the latter.

Comment: @QuantumDot Post updated to make the question clearer.